# Appending d3.js to div from within a PHP class

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

Im working on a class to make dynamic charts inside a web application.
The application uses the bootstrap framework.

I have tried to change the append to "DIV" and other variants etc.

```
var svg = d3.select("'.$this->ChartDiv.'").append("div")
```

But the chart doesnt appear inside these pages.

Here is my class:

```
class Chart{

    //Public variables:
    public $tsvFile;
    public $JsonLocation;
    public $JS;
    public $ChartDiv;
    public $Width;
    public $Height;

    function Set($What, $Value){
        $this->$What = $Value;
    }


    //For json
    function BuildJson(){
                    $DataOut = '
<style>
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript">

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%Y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var svg = d3.select("'.$this->ChartDiv.'").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", '.$this->Width.')
    .attr("height", '.$this->Height.')
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("'.$this->JsonLocation.'", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
    });



  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Profit (Millions)");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
});

</script>';

        $this->JS = $DataOut;            
    }
}
```

To call this class ive used this:

```
$Chart = new Chart();
$Chart->Set("JsonLocation", "json_item.php?item=123");
$Chart->Set("ChartDiv", "#Chart");
$Chart->Set("Width", "450");
$Chart->Set("Height", "700");
$Chart->BuildJson();
echo $Chart->JS;
```

Basically, everything is printed as it should inside the page and when i try this in an empty php file, it shows the chart.

Now, i dont understand what i'm doing wrong so any guidelines would help.

Comment: Just a typo (but it might cause problems loading the script), you are missing the first `"` when setting the `type="text/javascript"` in your script tag.

Comment: @1cgonza didnt make a difference :/

Answer (score 0):

`var svg = d3.select("'.$this->ChartDiv.'").append("svg:svg")` finds your ChartDiv element, appends an SVG element to it and assigns the D3 representation of this SVG element to the variable `svg`. You then use this `svg` variable for adding elements to the chart.

When you replace `...append("svg:svg")` with `...append("div")`, you are appending the inner contents to a div instead of an SVG element, and that makes no sense, as `g` and `path` etc. are only valid children of and SVG container.

Also, you either need to wrap your javascript in something like JQuery's `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`, or make sure you output the javascript after all the required HTML has been output already, so that for example `ChartDiv/#Chart` exists already.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The problem is that there is no output to this either :/

Comment: Please see another suggestion in edit above. It's still a bit vague to me in exactly what way your code fails. Nothing is appended to #Chart? Are there javascript errors in your console?

Comment: Console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
(index):573 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
morris.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Graph container element not found`

Comment: The javascript you have included above validates, so hard to know where those errors happen.